# Image similarity algorithm needed other than SURF/SIFT/ORB using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, point-clouds

For a project I'm doing, I need to detect certain groups of images that are similar. I'm doing this by comparing a test image to a target image to see if their patterns match. For example, here is the target image:
[image: Target image]
And here are the various images that I would test against:
[image: Test image 1]
[image: Test image 2]
[image: Test image 3]
From my pattern recognition skills, image 1 matches the pattern of the target image.

To determine this using Python, I tried first using API services, but none of them could differentiate between patterns. I also tried using the SIFT algorithm with opencv, but that didn't work well enough either. Since I've heard that SURF and ORB are similar to SIFT, I haven't tried them. How can I match these images? I need an algorithm or third party service that would be able to correctly identify image 1 as the match almost 100% of the time.

Comment: Looks to me like double curves in each image. So I would suggest interpolating 2 curves from your points.  Then just compare at intervals of columns in the image.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, I'll try that. Do you have any suggestions on how to interpolate the curves in Python?

Comment: If you want to solve it with computer vision you could try chamfer matching.

Comment: those are point clouds. use algorithms and data structures appropriate for point clouds, instead of trying to work on illustrations (pictures of matplotlib plots) of your point cloud. this should not be approached as "image processing".